# Style by categories for items with no value in QGIS

Tags: qgis, categorized-renderer, style-manager

I need to style a shapefile by graduated, but some items has no value for that items. (eg. the limit for each categories are 0/99 - 100/199 - and so on, but some items has no value, that means that the real value is zero).
I would like to represent all items with no value in the first step (0/99) but I do not want to create records with value "0" for those items.

How can I solve it?

Comment: you stack a rule-based rendering to exclude your 'null' items and **under it** your set your sub-symbology ...

Comment: you mean that some feature have a null value (or an empty string) in the field you use for categorizing right ? but what do you mean by set them as=0 without creating record with value "0" ?

Comment: Categorizing/classifying automatically creates a category/class for all `ELSE` cases. How does this not satisfy your needs?

Comment: @J.R I have some items with no value and I want to represent it as if those are euqal to 0.

Comment: @Erik this is what I need but I do not find this option in graduated settings

Comment: Graduated is not categorized - behold the problem. Maybe you could add some details on what range of values you're talking about, what style you want to get, and why adding a "0" to current NULL-values is a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create your graduated symbols based on the following expression:

`if("data-column" IS NULL,0,"data-column")`

`"data-column"` is the field you did your graduation on before. This expression only adds a check, whether there is a value in this column or not, then assigns a `0` if the field is empty.